# Regular expression to match source data like 7px 7px 7px 7px?

Tags: regex, regular-language

I need a regular expression which would do the following -->

For example,

margin:7px 7px 7px 7px;

Should be compressed to -->

margin:7px;

(NOTE: The number may not be only 7,it can be any number. And the units can be in px|em|%|in|cm|mm|pc|pt|ex)

Comment: why don't you try an online compressor (such as this http://www.csscompressor.com/)

Comment: i am trying to code one but having problems with this thing

Comment: There is no real question in your "question". Clarify what you want.

Comment: @kleinfreund: OP wants to find 4 repetitions and replace it with only one.

Comment: @kleinfreund I think the implied question is "what regular expression will do this for me?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely possible in the specific case of being repeated 4 times.

Using backreferences, this is possible for a particular value of `n` the number of times the number is repeated.  In your case, `n = 4`.

This one matches any "unit" value made up of only alpha characters, i.e. "px", "em" or "foo", plus the special case "%".  It could be made more restrictive to particular units by replacing `\w*` with a more specific match like `(?:em|px|......)`

```
/^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\w*|%))\s+\1\s+\1\s+\1$/
```

For example:

```
// first four examples all match
echo preg_match('/^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\w*|%))\s+\1\s+\1\s+\1$/', '7px 7px 7px 7px');
1

echo preg_match('/^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\w*|%))\s+\1\s+\1\s+\1$/', '7em 7em 7em 7em');
1

echo preg_match('/^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\w*|%))\s+\1\s+\1\s+\1$/', '5px 5px 5px 5px');
1

echo preg_match('/^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\w*|%))\s+\1\s+\1\s+\1$/', '7% 7% 7% 7%');
1

echo preg_match('/^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\w*|%))\s+\1\s+\1\s+\1$/', '5.2cm 5.2cm 5.2cm 5.2cm');
1

// different value, no match
echo preg_match('/^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\w*|%))\s+\1\s+\1\s+\1$/', '5px 5px 5px 7px');
0

// not 4 elements, no match
echo preg_match('/^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\w*|%))\s+\1\s+\1\s+\1$/', '7px 7px 7px');
0

// different unit, no match
echo preg_match('/^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\w*|%))\s+\1\s+\1\s+\1$/', '7em 7em 7em 7px');
0
```

Comment: Sorry I missed the replacement bit... just use `'$1'` as the replacement value :-)

Comment: @leftclickben thanks for the answer, didn't know how to repeat it for 4 times..... good day

Comment: @leftclickben but i think --> (\d+(px|em|%|in|cm|mm|pc|pt|ex))\s+\1\s+\1\s+\1

this regex is more better!!

Comment: Yep and I said that in my answer, if you want to be more specific you can list all the unit values, I was just being a bit lazy with typing it out and making sure I got every unit type, or looking it up ;-)

Comment: Also I just updated my answer to allow decimal values like `5.2cm`

Comment: I am finally using this regex -->

/(\d+(\.\d+)?(px|em|%|in|cm|mm|pc|pt|ex))\s+\1\s+\1\s+\1/


This matches with ":7px 7px 7px 7px;" as well as ":7.7% 7.7% 7.7% 7.7%;"

Comment: You're missing the `^` at the start and the `$` at the end.  Check my answer again compared to the regex you posted above.  Regexs are very sensitive to missing characters :-)

Comment: @leftclickben Yes, i know that. I did this purposefully!!

Comment: At last, it is LIVE now --> [CSS Compressor & Minifier](http://webapps.compzets.com/csscompressorandminifier/) ....

A few couple of tests from you guys would be great. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are not asking for the special case 7, but for any number, where all four are the same. [One can prove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages), that there is no such regular expression.

Comment: Yes yes, the number can be anything. I am not referring to a special case 7.

Comment: Actually you can, please see my answer.  What I think it is _not_ possible with a single regex, in the _more_ general case where it has to match _any number_ of the same string repeated.

Comment: @leftclickben: Right. Looks like regular expression engines are more powerful, than what would be a mathematical regular expression.

Comment: Ohhh hardcore maths -- that's why my head hurt after merely glancing at that wikipedia page :-)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `(\d+(px|em|%|in|cm|mm|pc|pt|ex))\s+\1\s+\1\s+\1` with `$1`

`\d+` matches one or more digits
`(px|em|%|in|cm|mm|pc|pt|ex)` matches any one of mentioned units
`\s+` matches one or more whitespaces (for matching separation between each occurrence)
`\1` matches the first capture group i.e. the digits followed by units (4 times \1 requires 4 occurrences of digits+units)

For allowing decimal part also, use `(\d+(.\d+)?(px|em|%|in|cm|mm|pc|pt|ex))\s+\1\s+\1\s+\1`

Replacing with `$1` replaces the matched input with first capture group

Comment: This is for the magnitude+units part and not including the label. What was your input and output?

Comment: Maybe make that group around the unit types a non-capturing group `(?:px|em|...|ex)`?

Comment: @RamBonbonPortent I tested it in java as well as using http://www.regular-expressions.info. It's working there. For input `7px 7px 7px 7px` output is `7px`

Comment: @NaveedS thanks for the answer, didn't know how to repeat it for 4 times, thanks

Comment: Hmm, I just noticed that this doesn't accept decimal values like `5.1cm`.